# Spammed with fake user registration

Tags: magento-1.6, user

After migrating a Magento webshop to a new host, there suddenly these 2 last days appears hundreds of fake user registration users. They have name like nzyaffmrtk , lrdrbzcuca  and weird emails.. Does anyone know why? What can I do to stop this? With out adding an extension that will rewrite the core files.

Comment: Are you really using Magento 1.6?

Comment: Yes, got the files from the old hosting company some days ago, they havent updated it.. But Im gonna do it, hope it will not break the site after updating.. but it is not therefore I got the spam registrations u think?

Comment: Why don't you just put a Capcha on your registration? This one works in 1.6 http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/contacts-form-captcha.html

Comment: Yeah, but will it work the same on the new user registration, or only on contact us form?

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly add what one would call a 'bot trap' into your registration page.  You see, bots don't have eyes.  And without eyes the only way to fill out a form is via field automation.  Therefore, they must 'feel' for the fields within a form. So, how do you trick a blind robot?  You create an invisible field called something official sounding like 'nickname' and then filter your applications thusly.

How does this play out in the real world?  A person, being non-mechanical and (hopefully) having at least one optical field searching mechanism will never find (nor click, nor type into) this invisible field.  However, robots, being very much the opposite will happily fill out every single field on the page.

In the backend just reject all applications with this field filled in.

:D